# I get a trouble when trying to set the same background fixed to the pseudo elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

Currently I'm working on a header that looks like a broken mirror, to accomplish this task I'm using pseudo elements that repeats the same background image of their parent and setting the background attachment to fixed, additionally I'm using the skew transform property so that it has a scroll parallax effect along with the mirror effect that it performs.

**The problem is that when I scroll the page down the pseudo elements' backgrounds reveal a white space. How can I fix that?**

The codepen link and images follows:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body { height: 100%; }

.mirror-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/dq5anctrd/image/upload/v1496258351/music-1970040_960_720_nqa715.jpg") no-repeat top fixed / cover;
}

.mirror-header:before, 
.mirror-header:after {
  content: "";
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  background: inherit;
}

.mirror-header:before {
  left: 0;
  transform: skewY(13deg);
  bottom: -80px;
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.mirror-header:after {
  right: 0px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 280px;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
  bottom: -50px;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

main .content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 200px 40px 40px;
}

main .content h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
}

main .content p {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<header class="mirror-header">
  
</header>

<main>
  <section class="content">
    <h2>Some Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero quis odit sunt, est, excepturi dolores ipsam expedita rerum laborum odio tenetur sapiente nesciunt omnis veniam necessitatibus neque animi velit nemo! Excepturi dolores ipsam expedita rerum laborum odio tenetur sapiente nesciunt omnis veniam necessitatibus neque animi velit nemo</p>
  </section>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</main>
```

[Scroll position bug IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owzWM.png)

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/gustavohk14/pen/dRQVEq?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fun one!

You need to set your `transform-origin` for the pseudo elements that you're skewing or the backgrounds won't display correctly during off-screen rendering. (As you discovered.)

**For Example:**

```
.mirror-header:after {
   ...
   transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

.mirror-header:before {
    ...
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
```

After doing this, you'll need to readjust the placement of the pseudo-elements to your liking.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body { height: 100%; }

.mirror-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/dq5anctrd/image/upload/v1496258351/music-1970040_960_720_nqa715.jpg") no-repeat top fixed / cover;
}

.mirror-header:before, 
.mirror-header:after {
  content: "";
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  background: inherit;
}

.mirror-header:before {
  left: 0;
  transform: skewY(13deg);
  bottom: -180px;
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.mirror-header:after {
  right: 0px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 280px;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
  bottom: -150px;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

main .content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 200px 40px 40px;
}

main .content h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
}

main .content p {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<header class="mirror-header">
  
</header>

<main>
  <section class="content">
    <h2>Some Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero quis odit sunt, est, excepturi dolores ipsam expedita rerum laborum odio tenetur sapiente nesciunt omnis veniam necessitatibus neque animi velit nemo! Excepturi dolores ipsam expedita rerum laborum odio tenetur sapiente nesciunt omnis veniam necessitatibus neque animi velit nemo</p>
  </section>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</main>
```

**[Working Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgqMXr)** forked from your original example.

***Aside***: Personally, I'd try to use `perspective`/`rotateY` for this instead of `skewY` as it could possibly give you a more "natural" distortion effect for your mirror shards, but that's my $.02.

Comment: Sorry. It's American slang for "but that's just my opinion, for what it's worth (and it isn't worth much)". Glad to help! Cool effect!

Comment: Ahhh, got it! loool